# lualatex keeps tex source open on error

Tags: luatex, emacs

I edit `LaTeX` source in emacs and invoke `lualatex` with `compile-command`. If the source contains an error the compilation stops and I see the reason in the `*compilation*` buffer. When I go to fix the error, emacs tells me I can't save the source file. It seems as if lualatex keeps it open. If I kill the compilation I can proceed.

The environment is MikTex 2.9, GNU Emacs 24.2, Windows 7.

This does not happen with pdflatex.

Any suggestions, other than changing my workflow?

Comment: Does your compile command use `-interaction=nonstopmode`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Add `-interaction=nonstopmode` in your compile command.
2. Use the `LaTeX` command of AUCTeX using `luatex` as `TeX-engine` value.